# Is it possible to resurrect an Windows XP operating system from the Windows.old folder?

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp

I had Windows XP installed on a desktop PC.  I installed Windows 10, thus changing the existing XP operating system Windows folder to Windows.old.

After 2 days on Windows 10 I want to go back to XP.  Is it possible to revert to the previous operating system without using a backup?  If so, how?

Comment: I'd suggest not moving back to XP, but instead posting questions about what problems you have with windows 10, and how to solve them. There's a number of reasons not to run XP now, and maybe a few valid ones for doing so.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you **really** should not run Windows XP just for the sole fact that it lacks security updates.

Comment: I still run XP for a couple of thousand (UK) pounds' worth software which I cannot upgrade to W10, but I am very careful about what I run in it. The questioner might want to consider running XP in a virtual machine.

Comment: There is no upgrade path from Windows 10 from Windows XP.  In this case, when you installed Windows 10, your prevous installation was lost.  If you had upgraded Windows 7 or Windows 8.x that wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this at some level but there's always a chance that the rollbacked window (Windows 10 to Windows XP) will not function properly at some point or limit the functionality of the system & OS at some level. However you can use "Windows.old" folder to restore your some of the data & settings.
If you really want to go back to Windows XP I will recommend you to perform a clean installation that will lead you to your system stability and help you get most of your OS features.
However there are some of the articles you may be interested to read to rollback your system (Some of the articles discuss similar methods but I am giving links so that it will help you clear your concept).
[Article 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971760/how-to-restore-a-windows-7-based-computer-to-a-previous-windows-installation-by-using-the-windows.old-folder), [Article 2](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-restore-previous-windows-version-after-upgrading-to-windows-10/), [Article 3](https://forums.yoosecurity.com/index.php?threads/how-to-use-the-windows-old-folder-to-restore-to-a-previous-version-of-windows.10161/), [Article 4](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/downgrade-windows-10-previous-windows-version/), [Article 5](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-ways-to-downgrade-windows-10/) and last one [Article 6](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3033806/microsoft-windows/how-to-roll-back-your-windows-10-upgrade.html).
[Note: *I am not responsible if you follow the above methods discussed in the articles and break down your system*.]
Anyway, I will recommend you to first test these methods in a Virtual Machine (you can use Virtualbox - a free program) weather these methods works the way you want so this will prevent you from damaging your actual system.
Make sure you have your Windows XP original *Product Key*, if you haven't noted it down then you can use "ProduKey v1.88" a great tool by NirSoft, to find your product key open the program and locate 'Windows.old' folder as your key source.

Program Links:
[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/),
[ProduKey v1.88](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)